# JPA - Real primary key generated ID for references

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, composite-primary-key

I have ~10 classes, each of them, have composite key, consist of 2-4 values.
1 of the classes is a main one (let's call it "Center") and related to other as one-to-one or one-to-many.

Thinking about correct way of describing this in JPA I think I need to describe all the primary keys using @Embedded / @PrimaryKey annotations.

***Question #1:***
My concern is - does it mean that on the database level I will have # of additional columns in each table referring to the "Center" equal to number of column in "Center" PK?

If yes, is it possible to avoid it by using some artificial unique key for references? Could you please  give an idea how real PK and the artificial one needs to be described in this case?

*Note:* The reason why I would like to keep the real PK and not just use the unique id as PK is - my application have some data loading functionality from external data sources and sometimes they may return records which I already have in local database. If unique ID will be used as PK - for new records I won't be able to do data update, since the unique ID will not be available for just downloaded ones. At the same time it is normal case scenario for application and it just need to update of insert new records depends on if the real composite primary key matches.

***Question #2:***
All of the 10 classes have common field "date" which I described in an abstract class which each of them extends.
The "date" itself is never a key, but it always a part of composite key for each class. Composite key is different for each class.
To be able to use this field as a part of PK should I describe it in each class or is there any way to use it as is?
I experimented with @Embedded and @PrimaryKey annotations and always got an error that eclipselink can't find field described in an abstract class.

Thank you in advance!

PS. I'm using latest version of eclipselink & H2 database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See,

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Composite_Primary_Keys

For info on composite keys.

Normally using a single generated id is better, but if you have legacy data you can use a composite key.

I would not recommend using an @EmbeddedId, instead use an @IdClass, it is much simpler.  EclipseLink does not require the @IdClass, but if you wish to use find() then you need one to compose the key values.

You should be able to use a @MappedSuperclass do define one of the id fields, ensure you annotate each key field with @Id.

EclipseLink does allow using the @PrimaryKey annotation to simplify specifying a composite key, you just need to give the list of columns.  You still must map those columns to attribute in your class.

Answer (score 3):

My advice: forget about functional composite keys: they're inefficient, and a nightmare to use. Just use a single-column, autogenerated key for all of your entities. This will also hav the advantage of making your tables shorter and cleaner (less columns).

That doesn't prevent you for creating a unique constraint on a set of columns, to make sure that, for example, there is only one record with a, b and c for the columns col1, col2 and col3.

And if you want to check if a record already exists for a, b, c, the just create a query:

```
select center from Center center 
where center.col1 = :col1 
and center.col2 = :col2
and center.col3 = :col3
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using @Table(uniqueConstraints={.. to define composite unique keys. Regarding the way to check if that object already exists - I load objects in chunks, each of them has ~400 instances, sometimes  ~50% are new and ~50% matches the unique key and needs to be updates. I'm thinking about avoiding the additional select statement for 50% of chuck and just update it right away if unique key matches.... Do you see any way to do it more efficiently than run select for each?